# Resize (height and width) of an prefixIcon of TextFormField in Flutter is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
final password = TextFormField(
  autofocus: false,
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Password',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
    prefixIcon: new ImageIcon(
      new AssetImage('assets/ic_email.png'),
      size: 15.0,
    ),
  ),
);
```

I have set size to 15.0 but nothing change, so please guide me, where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just got the solution by setting the property in **Image.asset**, please try below approach

```
final password = TextFormField(
  autofocus: false,
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Password',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
    prefixIcon: new IconButton(
      icon: new Image.asset('assets/ic_email.png',width: 15.0,height: 15.0,),
      onPressed: null,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this

```
TextField(
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,

              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                prefixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    'assets/your_image_here',),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),

                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: AppString.searchName,
              ),

            )
```